# Xinput does not work on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, sdl, visual-studio-2012

After moving from VS2010 to VS2012, Xinput has stopped working on Windows 7.

I get the following missing dlls:

- XINPUT1_4.DLL
- api-ms-win-eventing-classicprovider-l1-1-0.dll

Note that everything works as expected on Windows 8.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: _"porting my codebase from VS2011"_  Do you mean Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 17):

I'm using VS 2012 on Windows 8, but I got the same problem when one of my team members tried to run my program on a Win7 PC. Managed to solve it by changing xinput.lib; to XINPUT9_1_0.LIB; in Poject Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

For more info on the Xinput versions check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh405051(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4):

I got the same thing with `XInput`, moving a project from VS2010 to 2012 on Windows 7. Seems VS2012 comes with a new "XInput.h" which expects XInput1_4.dll.

All I had to do to fix it was change my dependency from XInput.lib to XInput9_1_0.lib (that's the old version).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue in the following way:

In VS2012, directx libraries are included on-disk. This is a new version of the library that only seems to work on Windows 8, and there does not seem to be a redistributable at this point.

As a workaround, you can link to the old sdk

1) Install the old direct x sdk
2) Under Additional Library Dependencies: $(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86;
3) Under Additional Dependencies: xinput.lib;